# sticky position not working for viewport height less than 500px

Tags: html, css, web, sticky

I am having a strange problem with the sticky position in CSS.
I want an element to stick to the bottom of the page and it is working perfectly if the viewport height is greater than or equal to 500px but if it is reduced any further then the element no longer sticks to the bottom of the page

This is how the sticky element looks like

```
 .sticky{
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 90%;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: var(--tl-dark-theme);
}
```

This is the container of the sticky element

```
section {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a clash of styles once you go below 500px height. In this styling:

```
 .sticky{
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 90%;
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: var(--tl-dark-theme);
}
```

If you have a height less than 500px then the top of the sticky element is less than 50px from the bottom of the container but its height is fixed at 50px.

What do you want the element's height to be when the overall height is less than 500px? You could for example have max-height: 50px instead of setting height.